# Vectors and Projection

Tags: vector-spaces

So i have 3 points. E = (0, 0 ,-5) C = ( 0, 0, 0) S = (-5, 0, 9). 
I am given several equations that work perfectly. I understand how to do the math, but I am trying to visualize whats going on.

So first I do E - C to get the vector(0, 0, -5). We will call this vector n.
Now i calculate a lambda that is (n dot ( C - S) / n dot n). Dot being dot product.

Is this the projection of C-S onto n? For some reason I don't think it is, because C-S is a vector to C.So i have a vector from C to E and a vector from S to C, but for it to be projection wouldn't it need to be C to S?

Hopefully I was able to explain what I am trying to visualize.

Comment: For this and the future, would you mind formatting your posts a bit cleaner? In particular: Use full grammar, punctuation, capitalization, and spelling; and can you separate parts out so that it isn't a wall of text? For super bonus points, you can use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make it really appealing.

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is a scalar. The projection of a vector is a vector. So, no.